# Need help parsing imported json data with VUE.JS JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, vue.js, javascript-objects

I need to import JSON data and pull out specific things from it and am having trouble doing it.

This is the sample data:

I want to try and pull out the name, description, and professor for each one.

I import the data like so:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a `computed` property
2. Use [**Object.values**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to return an array of the
   `proposedCourses` object properties values
3. Use [**Array.prototype.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the `name`,
   `description` and `professors` properties of each object.

The computed property will return:

`Object.values(this.proposedCourses).map(({ name, description, professors }) => ({ name, description, professors }))`

---

After that, use `v-for` to iterate over the `computed` property.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      proposedCourses: {
        "0bEiO5zcBCHv3Wd2lxHjjRepB": {
          "name": "math",
          "credits": 4,
          "professors": [
            "Samatha"
          ],
          "description": "come and learn some math",
          "prereqs": "",
          "comment": "",
          "maxEnrollment": 100,
          "times": [{
              "day": 2,
              "start": 900,
              "end": 1100
            },
            {
              "day": 4,
              "start": 900,
              "end": 1100
            }
          ],
          "departments": [
            "mathematics"
          ],
          "submitted": true
        },
        "BsSbrbjTH5FyV7gWdPjeDPqpw": {
          "name": "biology",
          "credits": 4,
          "professors": [
            "Reuven"
          ],
          "description": "learn about biology and stuff",
          "prereqs": "",
          "comment": "",
          "maxEnrollment": 20,
          "times": [{
              "day": 3,
              "start": 900,
              "end": 1100
            },
            {
              "day": 4,
              "start": 900,
              "end": 1100
            }
          ],
          "departments": [
            "biology"
          ],
          "submitted": true
        }
      }
    }
  },

  computed: {
    courses() {
      return Object.values(this.proposedCourses).map(({
        name,
        description,
        professors
      }) => ({
        name,
        description,
        professors
      }))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="{ name, description, professors } in courses" :key="name">
      <p>{{ name }}</p>
      <p>{{ description }}</p>
      <p>{{ professors }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use like

```
for(var prop in data) {
    var obj = {
        name: prop.name,
        description: prop.description,
        professor: prop.professor
    };
    console.log(obj); // U can use this obj object to applu your further logic
}
```

Comment: My data has multiple of each. also are you allowed to use var in vue?

Comment: `var` is allowed in JS, though `let` and `const` are becoming more common to enforce mutable/immutable variables/objects. Also, this works fine per his example, and will work for displaying purposes fine.