# How to get data from JSON? My v-for loop is not working

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to get data from a external json but the v-for loops does not work. Previously, with the same code I was able to show the data I don't know whats happens now.

This is the code i'm using:

`

```
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h1>Llista Valors</h1>

            <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 2%" v-for="dada in list">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Hora: {{dada.lists.hora}}
                    Preu: {{dada.lists.preu}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h1>JSON</h1>

            <pre>
                {{ $data }}
            </pre>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>`
```

`

```
    var url = "http://172.17.100.3/api/tarifa2.php";

    new Vue({

        el: '#main',
        created: function () {
            this.getApi();
        },
        data: {
            lists: []
        },
        methods: {
            getApi: function () {

                this.$http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                    this.lists = response.body.valors;

                });
            }

        }

    });

</script>`
```

This is what i get:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need help parsing imported json data with VUE.JS JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711907/need-help-parsing-imported-json-data-with-vue-js-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data should be called `list:[]`, not `lists:[]` to match your template.  Or rename your template to `in lists`.

Comment: You have to also change it in your getApi() function.

Answer (score 1):

For each `dada in lists`, there is no `dada.lists.hora` or `dada.lists.preu`.  There is only `dada.preu` or `dada.hora`.

Each `dada in lists` is like saying `lists[0]` (or whatever index).

So try changing the template to just `{{data.hora}}` etc as needed (after doing the list/lists adjustment per above).